# How to handle loadbalancing with 1 virtual IP/IP for many domains in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

RightNow, In Nginx vhost configuration files, we are using only 1 virtual IP (z.z.z.z) for many domains.

Eg:
        listen z.z.z.z:80; for www.test.com
        listen z.z.z.z:80; for www.play.com

Similarly, 
In Haproxy, we are using virtual IP with different ports for configuring different load balancers having different domains

Virtual Ip1: x.x.x.x
Virtual Ip2: y.y.y.y

For Example : IP x.x.x.x:8001 for Particular LB(Say xxx.test.com) and IP x.x.x.x:8002 for another LB(yyy.test.com)

Similary      IP y.y.y.y:8001 for Particular LB(Say aaa.test.com) and IP y.y.y.y:8002 for another LB(Say bbb.play.com)

Now does google load balancer provides this same functionality?

So far what we found was..it works only for one sub domain (that means..we need to configure many ips for each LB)

that is..
that load balancer can be configured only for test.example.com

if we want loadbalancer for test1.play.com, we need to configure a public ip and point that on our dns that public ip to test1.play.com

Comment: You can configure more than one HTTP Load Balancer Frontend. You can also do path based routing (rules). The IP address does not matter. It is the HTTP headers that are processed to determine the DNS hostname and to route to the desired backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure all your DNS zone from both domains to point the HTTP(S) LB IP address in GCP as A record type. At load balancer level, you must define [url maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#adding_a_host_rule) for each domain. Then you must create individual host rules for both domain, 1 for test.com and antoher one for play.com.

The backend configuration, I mean webserver (Apache, Nginx,etc) must be able to redirect traffic that match those host rules to the correct domain